# Integral In Ramanujan's Letter To G.H. Hardy

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, functional-equations

In Ramanujan's first letter to G.H. Hardy he defines a function $\phi(n)$ as such

$$
\phi(n) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos n x}{e^{2 \pi \sqrt{x}}-1} d x
$$
And then he gives a functional equation

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n x}{e^{2 \pi \sqrt{x}}-1} d x=\phi(n)-\frac{1}{2 n}+\phi\left(\frac{\pi^{2}}{n}\right) \sqrt{\frac{2 \pi^{3}}{n^{3}}}$$
How does one prove this functional equation? I am relatively unfamiliar with the methods one would use to solve this, and therefore do not have a proper attempt to share in this question. Thank you

Comment: http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram12.html Maybe you can use this.

Comment: Perhaps use the fact that they are real and imaginary parts of an analytic function and one may be found from the other via a Hilbert transform.